# I don't understand the compiler errors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

This is a homework assignment, so I am not wanting you to completely write the missing code. But I need a pretty hard push because I am new and need to get familiar with what I am doing.

This is a formatpiece used in AddDetailsblablablafunction()

```
#define REPLNEFORMT3 "       %-7s%7f%4f\n"
```

Line 51 is a prototype of function

```
51 void AddDetailToAccumulators(float *totpayrate, *float p);/
```

Line 85 is In the main mopdule and calls the AddDetailToAccumulators() function

```
 85 AddDetailToAccumulators(float *totpayrate, *float p);

171 void AddDetailToAccumulators(float *totpayrate, float *p)//3.6
172 {
173 totpayrate = p + totpayrate;
174 }
175 void PrintSummaryReport(float totpayrate, FILE * reportfile)/*, float  totreg, float *totovt, float totg, float totfed,
176 float totstate, float totssi, float totnet, 
177 int numemps, FILE *reportfile)//3.7*/
178                 
179 {
180 fprintf(stdout,REPLNEFORMT3,totpayrate);
181 fprintf(reportfile,REPLNEFORMT3,totpayrate);
182}
```

The compiler errors are listed as follows:

```
g++ -Wall -o "main" "main.cpp" (in directory: /media/dylan07/541C-D0D8)
main.cpp:51:49: error: expected identifier before ‘*’ token
 void AddDetailToAccumulators(float *totpayrate, *float p);//, //float *totp, float reg, float *totreg,
                                                 ^
main.cpp:51:50: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘float’
 void AddDetailToAccumulators(float *totpayrate, *float p);//, //float *totp, float reg, float *totreg,
                                                  ^
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:85:29: error: expected primary-expression before ‘float’
     AddDetailToAccumulators(float *totpayrate, *float p);
                             ^
main.cpp:85:49: error: expected primary-expression before ‘float’
     AddDetailToAccumulators(float *totpayrate, *float p);
                                                 ^
main.cpp: In function ‘void AddDetailToAccumulators(float*, float*)’:
main.cpp:173:19: error: invalid operands of types ‘float*’ and ‘float*’ to binary ‘operator+’
  totpayrate = p + totpayrate;
                   ^
main.cpp: In function ‘void PrintSummaryReport(float, FILE*)’:
main.cpp:180:40: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char*’, but argument 3 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
  fprintf(stdout,REPLNEFORMT3,totpayrate);
                                        ^
main.cpp:180:40: warning: format ‘%f’ expects a matching ‘double’ argument [-Wformat=]
main.cpp:180:40: warning: format ‘%f’ expects a matching ‘double’ argument [-Wformat=]
main.cpp:181:44: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char*’, but argument 3 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
  fprintf(reportfile,REPLNEFORMT3,totpayrate);
                                            ^
main.cpp:181:44: warning: format ‘%f’ expects a matching ‘double’ argument [-Wformat=]
main.cpp:181:44: warning: format ‘%f’ expects a matching ‘double’ argument [-Wformat=]
Compilation failed.
```

I hope my formatting is good. :)

EDIT: BurningLights, I love you!

Comment: `#define REPLNEFORMT3 "       %-7s%7f%4f\n"` and `totpayrate = p + totpayrate;` What? Is that what you get taught?

Comment: The "%-7s%75\n" Yes that was taught in class. but totpayrate = p + totpayrate was me

Comment: Change "*float p" to "float *p" and try again

Comment: `*totpayrate = *p + *totpayrate` ..isn't it?

Comment: @GeekyDewd The `#define` thingy too? That's, erm, an interesting way to do this. But I guess if you are going to use C output, why not do this too.

Comment: @coderredoc Yes, thank you.

Comment: @BaummitAugen What do you mean? I'm not sure as to why he is having us do certain things a certain way. But he is currently only allowing us to use stdio and NOT iostream

Comment: @GeekyDewd The `printf` family is inherited to C++ from C, most of the time, the C++ streams are more appropriate. But if your teacher does not allow you to use them, I guess you gotta do what you gotta do. Even more with the `#define` stuff: Highly dubious and rarely appropriate in C++, normal design tool in C. But I guess it kind of fits with the C output.

Comment: @BaummitAugenIm sorry, but I didn't follow that. Can you explain it to me in idiot form?

Comment: Using `#define` like this and using `printf` are both pretty terrible ideas in C++.  Your teacher is an idiot.

Comment: @GeekyDewd Long story short: `printf` does not play all to nicely with the C++ type system and is often easier to get wrong; `#define` has the problem that a) the compiler and the programmer see different things and b) many people use it for stuff that could be done way better/safer/easier with C++ features.

Comment: Similar thing with those pointers. Pointers definitely have their place in C++, but `void AddDetailToAccumulators(float *totpayrate, float *p)` would not pass my code review. This is C-style use of pointers, if you really want a function like that (what for btw? It does not make the code clearer IMO.) it should accept a reference and a `float` by value. (Also why `float` and not `double`?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so here's why you're getting your errors.

For the first and second errors, your `*float` should be `float *`. Doing `*float` doesn't mean anything to the compiler, and so generates an error. Doing `float *` on the other hand, tells the compiler your want a pointer to a float, and is perfectly valid.

For the third and fourth errors, you made the mistake of including the types in your function call. Don't do this! It generates an error. Simply remove the types so it looks like `AddDetailToAccumulators(totpayrate, p);` and that will fix your errors, assuming totpayrate and p are pointers to floats defined in your main function.

For the fifth error, you're trying to add two pointers together. That doesn't work! I assume you're trying to use the values that are pointed to, so you need to add the dereference operator (*) to make it look like: `*totpayrate = *p + *totpayrate;`.

For the sixth error and the warnings, your format string `"       %-7s%7f%4f\n"` tells `fprintf()` that it should expect a string argument, and then two float/double arguments to be able to write out to the output stream in the specified format. However, you proceed to only give it a single float argument. I can't exactly tell you how to fix this one, since I don't know the intent of the format string, or what you're supposed to be printing. I can tell you that you'll either need to change your format string so it only needs a single float and no string, or add more parameters to your `PrintSummaryReport()` function so you can give `fprintf()` what your format string tells it that it should expect.

Answer (score 0):

On line 51 the compiler is telling you that the indirection operator(*) is used but you don't have a type declaration before it, so change to float * p.

On line 173 it's telling you that you didn't give enough format arguments for the string REPLNEFORMT3, it expects 3 but you only gave it one.